# Image File in Hex Data (RGB888) to BMP,JPG,PNG or something else

Tags: c++, image, hex, rgb

I got the following problem, that I got image files in (supposed to be RGB888) but I'm not sure if it realy is this kind of data. (I only know the supposed format (e.g. 400 * 600) of the data, that's why I made a sample data of a picture, where I exactly know which format the hex data has.)

The Data I created looks something like this:

```
0xf3, 0x8d, 0x4c, 0xff, 0xf2, 0x8f, 0x4b, 0xff, 0xef, ...
```

I'm in this case sure, that this is RGB888 because I converted it.
So the first step I did was, to load the file and stream the data to a char array.

```
std::ifstream infile;
char *array;
uint8_t *pixelValues;

infile.exceptions ( std::ifstream::failbit );
try {
  infile.open(filename, std::ios_base::binary); 
    infile >> std::hex >> std::setw(2) >> std::setfill('0');  
    int length;

    if (!infile.bad()) {
        length = infile.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::end);
        array = new char[length];
        infile.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::beg);
        infile.read(array, length);
        infile.close();
    }

    uint8_t value;
    pixelValues = new uint8_t[length/5];

    std::size_t counter = 0;
    std::size_t valueCounter = 0;

    while (true) {              
        value = strtol(&array[counter], NULL, 0);
        pixelValues[valueCounter++] = value;

        while ((array[counter] != ',')) counter++;  
        counter++;
        if (counter >= length) break;
    }
}
```

After this step, the data in uint8_t pixelValues should be a Bitarray of the Data in the File.

My question now is, how to go on... am I doing things right or are there 'smarter' ways of getting an image out of this hex data?

My kolleague told me, that I should go on with the next step by using openCV but I can't get it running at all.

If anybody of you guys has a smart idea, please let me know ;-)

Comment: [Saving a simple image buffer to png in C++](//stackoverflow.com/a/2289638)

Comment: It's unclear what is the width and height of the image. You have `length` but I can't tell what that represents. `length/5` is also a mystery. OpenCV is overkill for saving image to png, but it will work. If you are having problems running OpenCV then investigate that separately.

Comment: length is the amount of characters... as the values of the input file gets saved in the format: 

    array[0] = '0'
    array[1] = 'x'
    array[2] = 'f'
    array[3] = '3'
    array[4] = ','
    array[5] = ' '
    array[6 to end] = and so on .... 

as there is always a minimum of 4 letters and minimum one ',' i divide by 5 as I don't know if there is any whitespace. valueCounter in the end will be the true length amount. It's just to save enough space. width and height are known values.

Comment: It seems you are writing to the file in plain text format "0xf3, 0x8d,..." then you read it binary mode using `fstream::read`. In text mode you are using 5 character to represent one byte. But in binary, each byte takes one byte, not 5 bytes. Either write in text mode and read in text mode, or write in binary and read in binary. The latter is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check when someone gives you a raw image and says it is 400x600 pixels RGB888, is to look at the file size and see if it is:

```
400 * 600 * 3
```

bytes which you can check very easily before they wander off leaving you under some false impression about the format and contents. So, is your file exactly 720,000 bytes?

---

If you want the **easiest** way to get a PNG or JPEG, you would simply use **ImageMagick** at the command line in Terminal/Command Prompt. So, if it is 400 pixels wide and 600 pixels tall and RGB888, you would do the following to get a PNG file:

```
magick -depth 8 -size 400x600 RGB:YourFile.dat result.png
```

If you want a JPEG, use:

```
magick -depth 8 -size 400x600 RGB:YourFile.dat result.jpg
```

---

If you didn't feel like installing **ImageMagick**, you could put a [NetPBM PPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) header on the front of the file in Terminal, like this:

```
printf "P6\n400 600\n255\n"  >  result.ppm
cat YourImage.dat            >> result.ppm
```

Then you will have a file that **Photoshop**, **GIMP**, `feh` and many other programs can read and save as PNG or JPG. Of course, you can do exactly that  same thing in 3 lines of C++.

---

If none that appeals to you, you can use [CImg](http://cimg.eu) - a brilliant, small, easy-to-use C++ image processing library. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51437576/2836621) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your respond! Can you tell me more about the three lines of code?

Comment: I'm not at a proper computer, but you open a file called `result.ppm` for write and write the `P6\n400...` stuff into that file. Then you write the entirety of your array to the file directly after the header and close it. That's all.